# 2 level Expandable List View in Android

Tags: android, accordion, expandablelistview

I am absolutely new to android, and in my project I need to add expandable list view of 2 level, can anyone help me, for the code? If possible, please share the full code with me, as on net, there are a lot of examples, but I was unable to understand the concept, as once, it was 2 level, but in child onlt textview, i want to add edit text and button too.. .. Plz help. Thanx in advance!

Comment: I doubt anyone would read your xml, and it is completely unclear what you really want.  If you provided an image instead of this xml, your question would probably be understandable.

Comment: Yes i know, I have images, but as i am new to this site so it's not allowing me to upload pics @18446744073709551615

Comment: I have upload my require picture at  <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=eujxqv" target="_blank"><img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/eujxqv.png" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read:

[ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

[ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

View visibility: [View.GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE), View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE.

I mean, you can get the functionality of an expandable list by hiding the detail views within a ScrollView.

Alternatively, ExpandableListAdapter has the method  [getChildView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildView%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29), you can make it return any view hierarchy you want.

On the image you provided I see 3 levels rather than 2, you may need to google-search for "android treeview".

Examples:

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/

http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.ru/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html

As to the concept, the adapter returns the child views that are shown. When the child views go out from the screen, they are placed into a reuse queue, so that if your screen can show 4 or 5 views (5 when the first and the last are shown partially), only 5 views will be created. You may have problems with buttons and edit boxes in child views, but you will likely find a solution on stackoverflow.

Comment: I already studied this link, I clearly mentioned that i am unable to understand the concept.., so i requested for the code and it's 3 level list, but for the word expandable, i interpret it 2 level... coz i need 2 such lists which expands!! Anyways Thanx

Comment: Try http://habrahabr.ru/post/147546/ (the code), http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2Fpost%2F147546%2F for translation (the translation is a bit schizophrenic, as usual)

Comment: http://my.eoe.cn/formyl/archive/18071.html

Comment: http://my.oschina.net/amigos/blog/62614